# NullPointerException in a 3D Matrix of two custom Classes in Java

Tags: java, class, matrix

I'm building a map, where i'm supposed to have costumers(Utilizadores class). The map is 2D, but i need to have a queue of costumers at each position(Posicao class). So it's basicly a 3D map composed by two different classes.

I think i'm building this the right way but for some reason, when i add a costumer to a position, i get a nullpointerexeption. Here is the code, of how i start the classes and what methods are being used for adding, since the start of the program.

Costumers:

```
public class Utilizador {
private String username;
private String password;
private int coordX;
private int coordY;
private boolean disponibilidade;
private boolean loginfeito;

private Socket sock;

public Utilizador() {
}

public Utilizador(String username, String password) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;

    this.loginfeito = false;

    this.coordX = -1;
    this.coordY = -1;
    this.disponibilidade = false;

    this.sock = null;
}
}
```

Position

```
public class Posicao {
private ArrayList<Utilizador> users;

public Posicao() {
    users = new ArrayList <Utilizador>();
}

public void addUser(Utilizador uti){
    this.users.add(uti);
}
}
```

The map:

```
public class Mapa {
private int dimX;
private int dimY;
private Posicao [][] utilizadores;

public Mapa(int coordX,int coordY) {
    this.dimX = coordX;
    this.dimY = coordY;
    utilizadores =new Posicao[dimX][dimY];
}

public synchronized void add(Utilizador a, int coordX, int coordY){
    this.utilizadores[coordX][coordY].addUser(a);
}

}
```

This is all being started by a server class, that contains a "mapa" and i'm starting it by using the Mapa (X,Y) constructor. When i make mapa.add(user,x,y), i get the nullPointerexception. My guess would be that the Positions are not being started properly probably, but i can't get why not... Can you tell what the error is?

Thank You :)

Comment: `new Posicao[dimX][dimY]` creates an array of `Posicao` filled with `null`s. You should also check the "coord" in `Mapa#add(Utilizador, int, int)`

Comment: @RC. Yeah that's what i thought, but how do i force it to use my Posicao() constructor? :/

Comment: @RC. you are probably right about the duplicate. That helped :) Thanks